# How to remove unwanted @charset "UTF-8" from CSS (shows up after compiling SASS files)

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, compilation, sass

A quick summary of our problem:

- We've got a @charset declaration prepended to our compiled CSS files
- Our SCSS files do not have this declaration so it gets added during compilation
- One of my co-workers says our site breaks in Safari if we have that declaration

SASS docs say:

> Output Encoding
>
> In general, Sass will try to encode the output stylesheet using the same encoding as the input stylesheet. In order for it to do this, though, the input stylesheet must have a @charset declaration; otherwise, Sass will default to encoding the output stylesheet as UTF-8. In addition, it will add a @charset declaration to the output if it’s not plain ASCII.
>
> When other stylesheets with @charset declarations are @imported, Sass will convert them to the same encoding as the main stylesheet.

Source: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Does anyone know a way to prevent SASS from adding it?
Does anyone know how we can check the "if it’s not plain ASCII" hypothesis on all our SCSS files?
Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have any UTF-8 characters in your CSS, even in the comments? What versions of Ruby and Sass are you running? Are you using Compass; which version? What charset do you expect the CSS to be compiled in?

Comment: Do you by chance use Codekit to compile the SASS? When I do, I too get a charset declaration in my compiled CSS files. When I compile it through the terminal/with gulp I don't.

Comment: @NilsKaspersson No, we don't use Codekit.

Comment: @KatieK We have characters in our comments like ø, ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167), sass-3.3.7, we are compiling with Grunt.

Comment: have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I wouldn't remove these. Still important in case if that CSS is cached. When browsers load cached CSS without encoding declaration, then unicode references to icon fonts might corrupt and you ll see bugs ...

Answer (score 4):

To add to this, I experienced this issue recently. We use gulp-sass to compile our CSS. From what I understand gulp-sass (which uses node-sass) have not provided any way to stop `@charset "UTF-8";` if there are non-ascii characters on your CSS. It was a problem for us because we wanted to use same CSS for our AMP pages. @charet is not allowed on AMP pages. Refer to this issue.

https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2288

**Our Solution**

What I did was to add a simple gulp task to remove the encoding attribute from the compiled CSS.

```
gulp.task('amp-sass-clean-up', ['amp-sass' /*Add gulp-sass task that compiles CSS*/], function() {
    return gulp
        .src(['/public/amp.min.css' /*This is the full path and file name to where your final css is*/], {cwd: '/public' /*This is the full path to where final css file is*/)
        .pipe(replace('@charset "UTF-8";', ''))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/public' /*This is the full path to where final css file is*/);
});
```

Comment: This is precisely what I did for the exact same issue. Note that the above example uses (presumably) the [gulp-replace plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) to perform the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know the `@charset` is very well support for all browsers, see also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset. Only "old" issues can be found, which only happen when `@charset` is not declared at the start of your CSS file. See also: https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/211.

When your are using grunt to compile your SASS files you can run an additional task after the compile task which removes the @charset declaration. https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace can do the replacement for you.

Comment: Thanks, yeah string replacement will work for me. In my case I am stamping a legal/contact header on processed output, which then appears before the encoding declaration... causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. I'm using prepros to generate email CSS that is transformed/inlined by the python Premailer library.

Below is a solution when using the Python premailer library, just subclass Premailer and change one function.

```
    import premailer
    # We need to patch a function to fix a CSS issue.
    class PatchedPremailer(premailer.Premailer):
        # Prepros automatically inserts this at the start of a CSS file,
        # but if we're using it inline in an email, it breaks things.
        re_charset = re.compile(r'\s*@charset "UTF-8";')
        def _parse_css_string(self, css_body, validate=True):
            if css_body:
                css_body = self.re_charset.sub(" ", css_body)
            return super(PatchedPremailer, self)._parse_css_string(
                css_body=css_body, validate=validate)
     # Run the patched premailer.
     print(PatchedPremailer(html).transform())
```